# Weird HTTP response using socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I have been trying to implement a persistent HTTP using socket programming. Once I have established a connection , I start requesting for each object sequentially. But once I have obtained the first object , I start getting weird HTTP response for the second object (in header )

```
sprintf(temp_buffer, "HEAD %s HTTP/1.1\r\n", objURL);
strcpy(req_buffer, temp_buffer);
sprintf(temp_buffer, "HOST: %s\r\n", host);
strcat(req_buffer, temp_buffer);
sprintf(temp_buffer, "\r\n");
strcat(req_buffer, temp_buffer);  

if (send(sockId, req_buffer, strlen(req_buffer), 0) < 0) 
{
    printf("send failed\n");
    return false;
}

char receiveBuffer[len];

int isRecvd = recv(sockId, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0);

if (isRecvd < 0 ) 
{
    cout << "Cant recieve !!" << endl;
    return false;
}

//Now to extract info from the Response
cout << isRecvd<<"\n";
receiveBuffer[isRecvd] = '\0';
string response = receiveBuffer ;
cout<<"the response is "<<endl;
cout << response <<endl;
```

The cout statement for response gives something like this : 
the response is ����吺��    vѴ�3��p .

Comment: Why are you using C-style string handling with `char[]` buffers for your HTTP request instead of using `std::string`?  And `char receiveBuffer[len]` is not valid C++ unless `len` is a compile-time constant, otherwise it is a non-portable extension. If you need a dynamic sized array, use `std::vector`. Either way, use `len` instead of `sizeof(receiveBuffer)` when calling `recv()`, Though, you are not really reading the server's response correctly anyway, not even close. I suggest you read [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 "Message Length"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) for details.

Comment: Also, what port is `sockId` connected to? 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS), or other?

Comment: Hi , I have used 80 as port no. I think the issue was as  that I was requesting pdf file with this code. There might be some characters in pdf that cannot be displayed. Other files work fine .

Comment: When requesting any file, binary or not, you would receive the server's textual response headers before the file data, but the output you showed does not display that. Did you not show everything you are actually receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are not showing your entire code, but is it possible you are not reading the first response completely? The server will either give you a content-length or a chunked response and you need to figure out how much to read before that response is complete. If indeed you are reading a fixed number of bytes `len`, then what you think is your second response is probably just more stuff from the first. Hope that helps.